# Get Data from stdClass Object TotalRecords

Tags: php, soap, request

```
<?php
$codiceagente= 5429;
$elepag = 0;
$numpag = 0;
class DateTime2 extends DateTime {
    function __toString() { 
        return $this->format("Y-m-d");
    }
}
$wsdl_path = "http://89.46.71.117:8000/WILLeuro/services/anagrafe?wsdl";
$date = new DateTime2();
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_path, array( 'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 'trace'=>1));

$result = $client->RicercaPratiche(array('request' => array('NagIntProduttore' => $codiceagente, 'ElementiPerPagina' => $elepag, 'NumeroPagina' => $numpag, 'DataLavoro' => $date."")));

print_r($result);


?>
```

and this my response:

```
stdClass Object ( [RicercaPraticheResult] => [TotaleRecords] => 19 )
```

How can I get the data from the various records considering that the indices range from `0` to `19` ?

Comment: Are you sure that is all of the result of your `print_r($result);` it looks a little odd to me

Comment: Please be careful **summarising** code or data. Thats not a valid class, so please show us all of the output from the `print_r()`

Comment: Hi if i use the client WCF i see this response:RicercaPraticheResult [0][1][2][3]. If i see RicercaPraticaResult[0] i have the xml response for [0]

Comment: <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <RicercaPraticheResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <RicercaPraticheResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Metoda.WILLeuro.Application.MainBoundedContext.DTO" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:RicercaPraticheDTO>

Comment: Nobody can help me? print_r($result->RicercaPraticheResult);
print_r($result->TotaleRecords); i have NULL and 19 with response...

Comment: Well I get `Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://89.46.71.117:8000/WILLeuro/services/anagrafe?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://89.46.71.117:8000/WILLeuro/services/anagrafe?wsdl"
 in...` when I run this

Comment: This server is accesible only from my computer...

Comment: Nobody can help me?